# Terraform import error resource address does not exist in the configuration

Tags: import, terraform

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "My access key"
  secret_key = "My secret key"
}

resource "aws_eip" "lb" {
  instance = aws_instance.myweb-server-instance.id
  vpc      = true
}

resource "aws_instance" "myweb-server-instance" {
   ami               = "ami-085925f297f89fce1"
   instance_type     = "t2.micro"
   availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
}
```

The resources that were imported are shown below:

```
c:\terraform> terraform import aws_eip.lb  
eipalloc-0ce64f24cdabcda76
aws_eip.lb: Importing from ID "eipalloc-0ce64f24cdabcda76"...
aws_eip.lb: Import prepared!
  Prepared aws_eip for import
aws_eip.lb: Refreshing state... [id=eipalloc-0ce64f24cdabcda76]

Import successful!

These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by 
Terraform.
```

But if I copy the above code and import statement in Azure Devops pipeline and run I am getting the following error:

> Error: resource address "aws_eip.lb" does not exist in the
> configuration. Before importing this resource, please create its
> configuration in the root module.

Please let me know what I am missing here. Thanks.

Comment: Its not clear how these AWS TF code relates to your  Azure Devops pipeline? How exactly are you using the pipeline? Do you have any config files for it?

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed my config file(elastic_ip) is not having .tf extension and terraform was not reading my config file. After adding the .tf (elastic.tf) extension now the import is working in Azure Devops pipeline.